# Z3Opt: Finding a sub-optimal model within a time bound?

Tags: performance, z3

Does Z3Opt have a functionality to provide a sub-optimal solution for the objective within a certain time bound specified by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a timeout or interrupt the opt context. You can then query the opt context for lower and upper bounds of the objective values. You can also query it for the current model and it will return the model for the best possible bound so far.

Comment: How can I do this in Java API?